# Why does one of my combobox is empty when my viewmodel is initialized from an xml file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 different comboboxes on my view. All of them are binded to 2 different dictionaries. I renamed a few stuff in my code.

```
public A SelectedFirst { get { ... } set { ... } }
public B SelectedSecond { get { ... } set { ... } }

public Dictionary<A, string> First { get; private set; }
public Dictionary<B, string> Second { get; private set; }
```

A is an enum type. B is a class with an int and string properties.

Both of them are binded the same way in my view.

```
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFirst}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{Binding First}"
></ComboBox>

<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSecond}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Second}"
></ComboBox>
```

The properties that are binded to SelectedValue are serialized into an xml file. My problem occurs when i run my code later or just simply re-run it by reloading everything from this xml file.

The problem is that with the type of enum ( A ) my combobox is automatically binded to the saved value but with the type of class ( B ) my combobox doesn't show the saved value. In the constructor of my ViewModel i see the saved value within the property but the combobox looks empty in the view. It seems to be a visual bug only but it's annoying.

Do you have any idea about what to do to fix it?

Comment: Dictionary is not observable. You need to call NotifyPropertyChanged when you are populating/reloading your dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In the class B to use PropertyChanged  to the Dictionary

```
 public  Dictionary<B,string>second;
 public  Dictionary<string,string>Second 
          {
                 get { return second ; }
                 set {
                        second= value;
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Second"));
                     }
          }
```

The xml is

```
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFirst}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{Binding First}"
></ComboBox>

<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSecond, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Second}"
></ComboBox>
```